# Chromes input border in red

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, border

I would like to use this css setting: `border-color: red;`
For `input` elements.
But when I do so, the metrics of them differ from the default chrome border.

Please look at this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/79QkJ/2/

There you can see that both input fields look different. But the only difference that should be visible is the red color, as you would excpect it.

**How to replicate the default style of input's just in another color?**

Comment: Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/79QkJ/6/

Comment: @VikasGhodke Then you override all styles. But you didn't create a duplicate of the chrome style in grey. To show you that look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79QkJ/7/

Comment: You do realize that `<input>` elements have a default padding of 2px that is being removed when you add the border? If you just want to replicate it you can re-add the padding in a new rule (accounting for the border-width) - http://jsfiddle.net/79QkJ/9/ - I'm just at a loss for *why* that happens ..

Comment: @Adrift I did not know that. But though, it does not work ^_^ . I'm thankful for trying to help, but please test your work before posting it. Your width still differs.

Comment: They have the exact same dimensions, inspect the elements with your browsers' developer tools (142 x 22)

Comment: Yes the `border-style` differs but they have the same dimensions - you can just use the `solid` value if you want them to be the same -http://jsfiddle.net/79QkJ/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style may look like `border-width: 1px;` but it is actually (at least in chrome) `border: 2px inset;`. The inset style doesn't really seem to work well with red.

You could use something like

```
border-color: 1px solid red;
padding: 2px 1px;
```

The default padding is `1px 0;` so that needs to be increased to `2px 1px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/79QkJ/13/

Comment: I forgot to add border-style: solid (as I assume that's what you want) so I edited the answer.

Comment: Funny that the OP marked this as correct when the two `<input>` dimensions are still not the same.

Comment: Thanks Adrift, actually the correct padding is `padding: 2px 1px;` I have edited the answer. The difference in height is a lot harder to notice than the width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

Comment: Doing that, will remove borders that appear on focus. But look at the width of my input fields. They are different!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt that be incorrect usage of the border?

" The border property is a shorthand for the following individual border properties:
    border-width
    border-style (required)
    border-color
"

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Leaving the browser space to think for itself.

Comment: Please post an answer, helping me solve the problem. (See that bold question).

Answer (score 0):

you can try it :

```
#red-input {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.1em;
}
```

Or also the meta boder property :

```
#red-input {
    border: 0.1em solid red;
}
```

Note I'm use to "em" for the size but you can also user "px".

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work. Please try your suggestion before posting it. Thanks anyway :)